# How to print a customized page in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I have added some `labels` and `textboxes` in a C# WinForm and I want to print that form with the layout that I set.

I tried doing this:

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.Jumbo_Load);

PrintPreviewDialog ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
ppd.Document = pd;
ppd.ShowDialog();
```

But this just opens a blank page. Not the one that I want to.

If someone can help me in that, it would be really appreciated.

Also, I have created SAP Crystal Report. How can I filter some record by using query? Because then, I can print that report.

Comment: What does “open a blank page” mean? Do you get a print preview dialog? Do you get a preview of your page in the dialog? Can you print it? If it prints, what's on the paper?

Comment: Do you have a method that handles the `PrintDocument.PrintPage` event?  I think that you need to implement the `PrintPage()` method.

Comment: @DourHighArch I don't get a preview dialog

Comment: What version of Crystal Reports are you using?

Comment: its Sap Crystal Reports 13.0.7

Comment: As far as handling it in a report, you should be able to filter your records by going to the `Report` menu, then `Selection Formulas`, then `Record`.  That will open a dialog where you can enter your filter criteria.

Comment: Sorry! but I didn't find the Selection Formulas. Are you talking about "Select Expert"?

Comment: I found it. Now, I want the courierNo to be imported from another form to this report, so that I can apply query to it. I tried doing this with the constructor, but its not working.

Comment: You will need to add a parameter to the report, probably called something like courierNo, and then pass the value to the report when you load the report.

Comment: give the code of Jumbo_Load method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have more code that follows, but I have a similar situation, which would look like so:

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.Jumbo_Load);

PrintPreviewDialog ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
ppd.Document = pd;
DialogResult result = ppd.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
    pd.Print();
}
```

Comment: Although, mine does not use a `PrintPreviewDialog` so that last bit may already be handled by the preview.

Comment: it doesn't work either Error 6 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)Page\Jumbo.cs 136 22 Login Page

Comment: Sorry about that, try changing it to `DialogResult result = ppd.ShowDialog();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

FROM MSDN

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern long BitBlt (IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
private Bitmap memoryImage;
private void CaptureScreen()
{
   Graphics mygraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
   Size s = this.Size;
   memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, mygraphics);
   Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
   IntPtr dc1 = mygraphics.GetHdc();
   IntPtr dc2 = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
   BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);
   mygraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
   memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
}
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(System.Object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
}
private void printButton_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   CaptureScreen();
   printDocument1.Print();
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't understand it, can you please explain it to me.

Comment: Place all code into your form and call these two lines where u want to print it.   CaptureScreen(); printDocument1.Print();